# Is SO a place for refactoring advice?

Tags: discussion, questions

I often ends up with refactoring question, such as "how do you make this code smaller?".

Typical example :

```
$(document).on( "click", '#el1', function(event) {
   ... do stuff...
 }); 

$(document).on( "click", '#el2', function(event) {
   ... do more or less same stuff...
 }); 

$(document).on( "click", '#el3', function(event) {
   ... do more or less same stuff...
 });
```

when I want it to be

```
$(document).on( "click", '#el1, #el2, #el3', function(event) {
   ... do the whole stuff...
 });
```

Is it ok to post these kind of questions on Stackoverflow ?

Comment: To go a little off topic; trying to make code smaller (in terms of characters) is almost always looking at things from the wrong direction; make code faster, more readable, more secure.  Not smaller; characters are free

Comment: Of course, however "smaller" makes sense when you have obvious code duplication like in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriated Stack Exchange would be [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Please note that questions on that site MUST absolutely contain **working code**, else the question goes on Stack Overflow.